# Formatting list items to alphabetize vertically and then horizontally when floated left

Tags: html, css

Assuming I have the following html:

```
<ul id="a">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ul#a {width:20px;}
ul#a li {float:left; width:10px;}
```

The current output is:

```
a   b
c   d
```

The output I'm going for is:

```
a   c
b   d
```

Is there any way to do this without breaking up the li's into two ul's?

Thanks,
-Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) may help you. It is from 2005 though, so it may be somewhat outdated. Still, it is somewhere to start.